# i18next get 404 response when there is no translation file

Tags: http-status-code-404, translation, i18next

I'm using `i18next-http-backend` to get translations.

Translation files:

```
en.json
pt.json
pt-BR.json
```

This is my config:

```
.init({
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  supportedLngs: ['en', 'pt', 'pt-BR'],
  nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true,

  backend: {
    backends: [
      LocalStorageBackend, // primary
      HttpBackend, // fallback
    ],
    backendOptions: [
      {
        prefix: 'i18next_res_',
        defaultVersion: version,
      },
      {
        loadPath: '${some-path}/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json',
        addPath: '${some-path}/{{ns}}/{{lng}}',

        queryStringParams: { v: version },
      },
    ],
  },
})
```

If the browser language is English (United States) `en-US` I get the `404 Not Found` error and then `en` is loaded.

When I add `load: 'languageOnly'` to the config, there is no `404`, but in this case it is not possible to load `pt-BR` languege. Instead `pt` is loaded.

I looked through the documentation, but did not find an option to fix this behavior.

Comment: Why does the 404 for en-US is a problem for you?

Comment: I guess it is not very good behavior to have an extra error request.

Answer (score 2):

comment of the "i18next" library developer:

"so if there is no en-US, but there is en and you're using load: 'all' or no load option, the en resources will be loaded. But before this, i18next tries to fetch en-US and if there are no en-US resources you'll see a 404...

If you do not like to "see" those 404 requests, you need to list all languages in the supportedLngs option and not set nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true

Said in other words: if you use nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true you can't prevent all 404"